# centos6 apache2 Invalid Command SSLEngine

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, mod-ssl

Running: CentOS6 x64

When I restart httpd, I get the following error.  What am I missing?

```
[root@localhost ~]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/sites.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I have installed mod_ssl using `yum install mod_ssl`

```
Package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

My sites.conf looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerName shop.itmanx.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@itmanx.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/shop-error.log
    CustomLog logs/shop-access.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName secure.itmanx.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@itmanx.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/secure.itmanx.com/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/secure.itmanx.com/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/secure.itmanx.com/chain.crt

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/shop-ssl-error.log
    CustomLog logs/shop-ssl-access.log    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SSLEngine on` won't work unless the ssl module itself is loaded.  You should have a line that looks like `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` somewhere.

In my installation, I have a file called `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` that specifies this LoadModule directive.  That file is part of the mod_ssl package that you said you installed.  Verify that the file is there, and that your primary httpd.conf file (typically /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.con) has a line that says something like `Include conf.d/*.conf` in it, so that all .conf files in /etc/httpd/conf.d are also read into the configuration.

(Oh, installing the openssh package is sort of irrelevant to getting SSL running in Apache)

Comment: i added the loadmodule line in httpd.conf and now its working hurrah!!!  thanks cjc

Comment: that was a typo on ssh, meant to write ssl... have corrected :)

Comment: Apache downloads modules in alphabetical order, that's why sites.conf was downloaded before ssl.conf and that was the root of the issue