# CentOS 6.6 Apache 2.2.15 Invalid Command SSLCARevocationCheck

Tags: apache-2.2, puppet, centos6, puppet-dashboard

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/358793/centos6-apache2-invalid-command-sslengine) which seemed to be related. But unfortunately I have the Include and the ssl.conf file. I have also verified the the revocation file exists and the path is correct. I have also set my SE Linux to permissive. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The directive doesn't exist in Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - read the (appropriate) documentation.

---

Finding random stuff on the internet is all well and good if you know what you're doing and read the documentation. It appears that the  [**SSLCARevocationCheck**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcarevocationcheck) directive is Apache 2.4 and not [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html)

Comment: I was starting to suspect that was the case: I just couldn't find it specifically stated anywhere. Thanks.